# logo with 3/4 curvy geometric parts

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What is the best possible way to create a similiar logo like this one?
I prefer to have 4 parts instead of 3. I'm already a bit lost with the start I have to make..
Cheers

[image: curvy logo]

Comment: Sketch. Take a piece of paper and a pencil or pen en try and sketch with you want to make. Then, scan or photograph that and base your work in Illustrator on that scan.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I sketch the logo already on paper (4 parts) and now I want to create it in Illustrator. Is the best way to use curving pentool or f.e. 4 retangles (bottom/top curved edges) and work from there onwards..

Comment: Then please add that information to your question, if possible including an image of your sketch. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks, got it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe

1. Draw one piece
2. Duplicate it, rotate 90°. Repeat until you have 4 pieces
3. Move pieces into place.
4. Use the Shape Builder to make fillable pieces, and fill with the desired colours.

Here's a rough example:

[image]

Comment: That's what I needed :)